# Как задать размеры страницы в iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Добрый день!

На странице есть iframe, в котором отображается страница с другого сайта, но ее размер превышает размер iframe и она обрезается.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как-нибудь задать размер того, что находится в iframe ?

Comment: Сделай скроллируемый iframe.

Comment: А без скроллинга можно обойтись ?

Comment: Нельзя. Если тот сайт сам под окно не подгоняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если страница на том же домене - да, вы имеете доступ и можете изменять с помощью js iframe

```
frames[0].contentWindow.document.body - body фрейма
```

Если располагаются не на одном домене, можно попробовать так:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwpJx/)

Можно вашим сервером получить и изменить страницу, выводить уже так, как захотите